# Is this DirectX (etc) question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I am referring to this question:

[Why do games install existing components each time I install a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266008/why-do-games-install-existing-components-each-time-i-install-a-game)

> When I install a game why does the installer also install DirectX, C++ libraries or .NET components that I already have?. Are these different versions or extensions? Or is is because the game installers are unable to find out what I already have installed?

...which is currently closed as a duplicate of this question:

[What is Direct X, and why do games keep on requesting different versions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265014/what-is-direct-x-and-why-do-games-keep-on-requesting-different-versions)

> I am not very experienced with computers, and was wondering what Direct X actually does, on my PC.
>
> Why do various games request different versions? Should the latest version cover all of them, or do certain games only support specific versions?

Comment: what wasyhe exact point of this? The questions already been reopened

Comment: This was raised before it was reopened.  Is that a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe these are exact duplicates.  In fact, they are both different questions completely.

The original is asking what does DirectX actually do, and why games cannot just use the latest version (rather than specific versions).

The newer question is asking why does an installation of a game result in the apparently same components being installed (and not just DirectX).

The only similarity between both questions is that they both mention DirectX (although the new question isn't specific to DirectX).  It is possible that part of one the original question's answers may partly answer, or at least offer some explanation to the new question.  However, it seems pretty inaccurate to group these as the same question for this reasoning.

The original doesn't address the fact that you'll see some "installing DirectX 11" message across multiple games, even though you have "DirectX 11" installed.  See one of the OP's comments:

> @DJPirtu I know what DirectX is and I have version 9 and 11, but games still want to install it

The newer question doesn't ask for an explanation as to why a later version cannot be used for an older version.  It is specifically concerned with the ***same*** version.